# How to make a dynamic number of input fields using Flatlist in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to make an input form for a team that does not have a fixed number of players and it should be optional on how many you enter without limits.

The idea is to have a button that puts an empty string into an array of team players which then FlatList should react to without refreshing the page and give you fields for input which would store the value on change without a button.

So it would something like this:

```
const TeamContentScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [list, setList] = useState([""]);


    const addToList = () => {
      let tempArr = list;
      tempArr.push("");
      setList(tempArr);

      console.log(list);
      console.log(list.length);
    };

 return(
     <View>
         <Button onPress={addToList} title={"+1 player"}/> 

         <FlatList 
             data={list}
             keyExtractor = {(e,i)=> i.toString()}
             renderItem={({item, index})=>{
                 return(
                     <TextInput
                     placeholder="Type player name here"
                     onChangeText={/*way to dynamically update the value of an element of this index*/}}
                     />
                 )
             }}
         />
 )
}
export default TeamContentScreen;
```

1. Is this possible?
2. If yes, how do you suggest dynamically updating the input fields display without refreshing?
3. How would you suggest storing the inputted values in the array without a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
const onChangeText = (value, index) => {
let newList = [...list]; // clone list to a new list
newList[index] = value; // change the value at the index of list
setList(newList); // set new list
}
<TextInput
placeholder="Type player name here"
onChangeText={(value) =>onChangeText(value, index) }
/>
```

Comment: add a debounce when changing input to avoid many re-render